# Use Jenkins build number within build.sbt in play to build RPM with sbt-native-packager

Tags: jenkins, playframework, sbt, sbt-native-packager

This question is somehow related to [Using Jenkins BUILD NUMBER in RPM spec file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155792/using-jenkins-build-number-in-rpm-spec-file).

You can access the build number in a Jenkins process using the environment variable `${BUILD_NUMBER}`. But how can I use this environment variable within my Play! `build.sbt` file to set `rpmRelease := "..."` to the actual build number?

The RPM is built within Jenkins using the simple Shell command `activator rpm:packageBin`.

Comment: I'm answering as a comment b/c I'm not sure, but one thing to try is passing arbitrary values to your application.conf. See the very bottom of https://playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Configuration.  So, in Jenkins, you could run a terminal command like `activator -DrpmRelease=${BUILD_NUMBER} dist`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can place scala code in your build.sbt file, so something like this should work:

```
rpmRelease := sys.env("BUILD_NUMBER")
```

or if you need to provide a default value:

```
rpmRelease := sys.env.get("BUILD_NUMBER").getOrElse("SOME DEFAULT VALUE")
```